# Static functions and variables in C

Tags: c, function, variables, static

I know what is the purpose of using static variables in an object oriented language, still, I don't understand what is the meaning of using the "static" keyword in C.
Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: What does OO have to do with it? Even the wikipedia definition should answer this question for you, no?

Comment: It has tons of different meanings. Post some code to explain which one exactly you're after, and say why your C text book doesn't cover this.

Comment: I know that on an object oriented language when you use static variables it is created only once per class, and not for each instance of the class. That's why I mentioned the OO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a function or global variable, `static` makes the function or global variable local to that file; other files cannot access that function or global variable by that name (but they can access it if you give a pointer to it away).

On a local variable, it makes it act as if it was a global variable, but is only accessible within that function (unless, again, you give a pointer to it away).

Comment: Also, global static functions/variables usually defend in .c files  but not useful in .h files... @icktoofay I am correct ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, you are correct; `static` is generally not of much use in header files (although I can think of a case or two in which they might be helpful).

Comment: I would request you please share your idea!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: One might desire to make a header file which declares a static boolean representing the module's initialization state (initialized to false, of course) and then provide macros which make it easy to define functions to initialize the module unless it has already been initialized.

Comment: Another use of `static` in headers is having functions that can be inlined by the compiler and staying C89 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The value that a **static** variable has upon leaving a function is the same value that variable will have the next time the function is called.

A **static** function can be called only from within the same file that the function appears.