# Is it an acceptable practice to declare a static const variable in a header file in C

Tags: c, header, declare

I have an array `static const char* keys[]`. Can I declare the array in a header file as

```
static const Char* keys[] = {
   "id",
   "ip", // a growing array.
}
```

or should declarations always be made in the `.c` file?

Comment: Might be using in some small piece of code in header file itself.

Comment: Read this two comments: [comment-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096470/static-functions-and-variables-in-c/13096505#comment17799663_13096505) and [comment-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096470/static-functions-and-variables-in-c/13096505#comment17799882_13096505)

Comment: So how do I give a pointer to the static array here if I want to use it in another file?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that would *work* but memory would be allocated for a new array every time you include the header file in a C file. That means that you would probably have several copies of the same array.

The usual way to do what I think you want is:

c file:

```
const char* keys[] = {
   "id",
   "ip", // a growing array.
}
```

h file:

```
extern const char* keys[];
```

That way you have only one memory allocation, and can reference this location in other modules.

An alternative would be to make the array `static` (nothing in the h file) and write get functions to access the strings.

What was your rationale for having `static`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's object definition in your question, declaration doesn't instantiate data structs/classes etc.
So if you move this object definition to *.c file then you can't access it from other sources. It is a static influence. Guess, this is not what you need.
But if you remove static and put definition to *.c and add declaration to *.h file then you save a memory for each include of a header file for size of your object (each include will be pointing to one const struct).
Now in your case every include will increase size of your binary at size of your object.